# Error Incompatible types in java

Tags: java

This is my code but it gives me this error

```
class MultiplyDivide {

  public static void main (String args[]) {

    int i = 5;
    int j = 10;

    System.out.println("5 is " + i);
    System.out.println("10 is " + j);

    int k = i/j;
    System.out.println("5/10 is " + k);
    k = i * j;
    System.out.println("5 * 10 is " + k);
  }
}
```

Comment: It will give no error!

Comment: Ther is no error in your code

Comment: I don't see any error even when I try running your codes on [here](http://www.compileonline.com) nor on my compiler.

Comment: The problem is probably not an error but an unexpected result (I guess that it has to do with integer division). Check double division if you want 5/10 == 0.5

Comment: When there is an error, always explain what the error is.

Answer (score 3):

**Hi,**

Actually the code that you posted should not give you an error.

It will return an output like:

```
5 is 5
10 is 10
5/10 is 0
5 * 10 is 50
```

One point that can be an error from your point of view is the 5/10 equals zero. But it is a correct java behavior because you are dividing integer by integer and assign a result to an integer.

If you want to get a double-type result you need to do something like:

```
double k = i * 1.0 / j;
```

Hope this resolves your issue.